# Agents and threads synchronization in Clojure

Tags: multithreading, join, concurrency, clojure

I have to rewrite this code using agents in someway the result of x is 0 (It means that each thread is executed one after one). But I have problems because I do not have enough knowledge about agents use.
The original code is:

```
(def x 0)
(let [t1 (Thread. #(dotimes [_ 10000] (def x (inc x))))
      t2 (Thread. #(dotimes [_ 10000] (def x (dec x))))]
  (.start t1)
  (.start t2)
  (.join t1)
  (.join t2)
  (println x))
```

When I want to use an agent with await(agent_name) to make each thread run separately, it does not work, the result is always different from zero.
Please any suggestions about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gave this a try and it prints `0` as expected:

```
(ns agent-demo.core
  (:gen-class))

(def counter
  (agent 0))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [t1 (Thread. #(dotimes [_ 10000]
                       (send counter inc)))
        t2 (Thread. #(dotimes [_ 10000]
                       (send counter dec)))]
    (.start t1)
    (.start t2)
    (.join t1)
    (.join t2)
    (await counter)
    (println @counter)
    (shutdown-agents)))
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I was stuck in this question. :D